# Question regarding AJV: can "useDefaults" be declared dynamically or later after instance is declared?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, json-schema-validator, ajv

Can we get a default json from all the defaults assigned in properties without using flag "useDefaults" as true, have a usecase where need to validate without using defaults but also want defaults, only way right now I can think of is using 2 instances. Can you suggest anything ?